# NodeJS + Jade variable number of blocks

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, express, pug

I've started my way into NodeJS development. And I'm facing a problem..

I have a main template - layout.jade that basically builds the bootstrap's top navigation bar on every single page. This is basically a music application where each artist has some number of songs. If you go on one of the artists' page, you can see the songs that the artist has. If the artist has 5 songs, he should have 5 blocks in this format:

```
block waveform
    div.waveform
        div.progress.progress-striped.active(id='progress-bar-#{songCount}')
            div.progress-bar(role='progressbar', aria-valuemin='0', aria-valuemax='100')
                span.sr-only
        h3.song-name #{songName}
        wave(id = '#{songCount}')
```

So the layout inheritance i wish to have is:

```
layout.jade
--artist.jade
----song.jade * (number of the songs the artist has)
```

The problem I'm facing is having multiples of song.jade inserted into the layout.. Yeah i can have javascript in artist.jade generating the html and appending it 5 times (if the artist has 5 songs). But is there any other way of doing this using NodeJS and Jade without clogging the client side?

Also, if I am doing something wrong, feel free to correct me/give an advice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution should fit your requirements:

```
each song in artist.songs
  li= song.name
```

However, it is not song.jade you insert at this point. This approach is, in my view, incorrect. You should instead attach the HTML template of song.